# Abrir un informe con varios IDs

Tags: vba, ms-access

Tengo un Recordset que ofrece datos con entre 1 y 10 registros.

Por otra parte, para llamar a un informe que muestra en cada página los datos de su tabla asociada dadas unas Id's:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ordentallerSobre", acViewPreview, , "ID IN (20346, 20347)"
```

El problema es conseguir cargar N referencias en esas Id's, pero no sé cómo podría....
Así se podrían cargar dos referencias usando variables, claro. Pero qué pasaría cuando fueran necesarias 3,4,5,6....hasta 10.

¿Alguien puede dar alguna pista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido a SO en español. Lo que te sucede ahora mismo es algo muy habitual en programación. Tienes N referencias, siendo N un número indeterminado, y necesitarías N variables. A veces 2, otras veces, 8, otras veces 10...etc.

Para ello, **necesitas usar matrices**, también llamadas *arreglos,arrays*. Por simplificar muchísimo la explicación, te diré que las matrices es una variable que permite guardar un conjunto N de valores. Pero te recomiendo encarecidamente que te leas el siguiente enlace en español por si quieres profundizar en matrices (**muy recomendable**):

> **[Matrices en Visual Basic](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/)**

Bien, sabiendo esto, dices que tienes un Recordset que te devuelve un número N de registros (entre 1 y 10). Supongo que en ese Recordset tendrás un campo ID. Los pasos a seguir serían:

1. Crearse la matriz
2. Redimensionar la matriz según el nº de registros devueltos del Recordset
3. Meter todos los ID en la matriz
4. Abrir informe

Desconozco donde están tus datos, así que tendrás que adaptarlo. Vamos a suponer que tienes un formulario que te devuelve el Recordset según lo que te interesa, y ya desde ahí haces click en un botón para llevar esos datos a un informe. Entonces:

```
Dim RST As Recordset
Set RST = Me.Form.RecordSet.Clone

RST.MoveLast
RST.MoveFirst

Dim MiMatriz() As Long
ReDim MiMatriz(RST.RecordCount)

Dim ZZ As Long
ZZ = 0
Do Until RST.EOF = True
    MiMatriz(ZZ) = RST.Fields("Id").Value
    ZZ = ZZ + 1
    RST.MoveNext
Loop

Set RST = Nothing

Dim EstosInformes As String


For ZZ = 0 To UBound(MiMatriz) Step 1
    EstosInformes = EstosInformes & MiMatriz(ZZ) & ", "
Next ZZ

EstosInformes = Left(EstosInformes, Len(EstosInformes) - 2) 'para quitar el último ", "

Erase MiMatriz

DoCmd.OpenReport "ordentallerSobre", acViewPreview, , "[ID] IN (" & EstosInformes & ")"
```

Espero que puedas adaptar este código a tus necesidades. Y de verdad, te recomiendo encarecidamente dominar matrices, porque son muy útiles.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo pruebo.